# Pytorch, efficient way extend a tensor by its first and last element

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor in pytorch. I want to extend it on a specific dimension from the beginning and the end by `k` positions with the first and last elements of that dimension respectively.
Say I have the tensor with data `[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]`. Operation `extend(dim, k)` would change it in this way:

`extend(0, 1)`:  [**[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]**, [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], **[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]**]

`extend(1, 1)`: [**0**, 0, 0, 0, **0**], [**1**, 1, 1, 1, **1**], [**2**, 2, 2, 2, **2**]]

What is an efficient way to do this (compliant with `tensor.requires_grad=true`)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`torch.nn.functional.pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.pad), with `mode='replicate'`.
However, there are two things you need to pa attention to to get this to work:
1. `pad` does not work with 2D tensors. Thus, you need to add leading singleton dimensions before `pad` and `squeeze`ing them afterwards.
2. The order of pad values `pad` expects is *opposite* to dim order.

```
import torch
from torch.nn inport functional
x = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], dtype=torch.float)
# expand along dim=0 by k=2 
f.pad(x[None,None,...], (0,0, 2, 2), mode='replicate').squeeze()
```

> ```
> Out[]:
> tensor([[0., 0., 0.],
>         [0., 0., 0.],
>         [0., 0., 0.],
>         [1., 1., 1.],
>         [2., 2., 2.],
>         [2., 2., 2.],
>         [2., 2., 2.]])
> ```

```
# expand along dim=1 by k=2
f.pad(x[None,None,...], (2, 2, 0 , 0), mode='replicate').squeeze()
```

> ```
> Out[]:
> tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
>         [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
>         [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]])
> ```

Comment: Thank you this seems like a feasible solution. However I am seeing this note in the docs so it is not an applicable one in my case: > When using the CUDA backend, this operation may induce nondeterministic behaviour in be backward that is not easily switched off. Please see the notes on Reproducibility for background.

Comment: Although I might be misunderstanding this statement. I interpreted it as, the gradients are not correctly computed on calling `backward()` is that the case?

Comment: @user2268997 I find it quite odd. Non zero padding is not so uncommon, I did not hear of anyone facing problems with the padding.